# how to fix error when connecting to openvpn?

Tags: openvpn

I want to use openvpn for anonymization. I download openvpn files and run command

```
openvpn --config vpn-file-name.ovpn
```

input login and password and see error

```
Tue Apr  9 21:48:03 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  3 2018
Tue Apr  9 21:48:03 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username: vpnbook
Enter Auth Password: *******
Tue Apr  9 21:48:14 2019 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue Apr  9 21:48:14 2019 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Tue Apr  9 21:48:14 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]51.68.180.4:443
Tue Apr  9 21:48:14 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
Tue Apr  9 21:48:14 2019 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]51.68.180.4:443 [nonblock]
Tue Apr  9 21:48:15 2019 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]51.68.180.4:443
Tue Apr  9 21:48:15 2019 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Tue Apr  9 21:48:15 2019 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]51.68.180.4:443
Tue Apr  9 21:48:15 2019 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]51.68.180.4:443, sid=107bf968 485bcb1f
Tue Apr  9 21:48:15 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Tue Apr  9 21:48:16 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=CH, ST=Zurich, L=Zurich, O=vpnbook.com, OU=IT, CN=vpnbook.com, name=vpnbook.com, emailAddress=admin@vpnbook.com
Tue Apr  9 21:48:16 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=CH, ST=Zurich, L=Zurich, O=vpnbook.com, OU=IT, CN=vpnbook.com, name=vpnbook.com, emailAddress=admin@vpnbook.com
Tue Apr  9 21:48:17 2019 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 1024 bit RSA
Tue Apr  9 21:48:17 2019 [vpnbook.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]51.68.180.4:443
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 SENT CONTROL [vpnbook.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS  213.186.33.99,dhcp-option DNS  91.239.100.100,route 10.9.0.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 10.9.1.102 10.9.1.101,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1627
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp3s0 HWADDR=54:13:79:b8:a2:75
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun1: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 Exiting due to fatal error
```

At the same time, a few weeks ago everything worked well. Whats problem?

Comment: have you tried with sudo?

Comment: yes. i do. but this is not working(

Comment: look into the error message `Tue Apr  9 21:48:18 2019 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun1: Operation not permitted (errno=1)`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/647231/getting-cannot-ioctl-tunsetiff-tun-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-con